# How to add Unity.WebAPI to a .net 4.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0, unity-container

I am trying to add Unity.WebAPI to a .net 4.0 project. The latest version, 5.1.0 is for .Net 4.5 so I am trying to use version 0.10.0. I've tried using the Nuget Package Manager Console to install this version using the command:

```
Install-Package Unity.WebAPI -Version 0.10.0
```

It installs successfully but the reference in my project is notated with the caution symbol as if there is a problem. When I try to build I get the following error message:

> The referenced component 'Unity.WebAPI' could not be found

Unity.WebApi is dependent on Unity which I have successfully installed version 2.1.505.0

One thing I have noticed is that when I go into my packages\Unity2.1.505.0\lib folder, I only have a NET35 and SL30 folder. I would think I would see a NET40 folder but that might be insignificant.

One other note is that I did try installing the later version of Unity.WebAPI version 5.1 which is dependent on Unity 3.0.1304.1 which is not compatible with .net 4.0.

I would welcome any ideas or suggestions on getting Unity.WebAPI installed on my .Net4.0 project. I'd also be glad to provide anymore information one might need to help.

Thanks in advance.